# Testing Spring.NET Injected Membership Provider

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-membership, integration-testing, spring.net

Loving the flexibility injecting the membership provider but I'm scratching my head trying to get integration tests to pass.  My web application version injects the membership provider with no problem in my service layer, but I can't get it configured/working properly in my unit/integration testing application version. Here is how I have everything configured for the membership provider.

App.config:

```xml
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="assembly://App.UI/App.UI/auth-config.xml"/>
      <resource uri="assembly://App.UI/App.UI/core-config.xml"/>
    </context>
  </spring>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="server=localhost;database=aspnetdb;User ID=AppWebUser;Password=p@ssw0rd" />
    <add name="appDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="server=localhost;database=app;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppWebUser;Password=p@ssw0rd"/>
    <add name="test_appDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
              connectionString="server=localhost;database=app_test;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppWebUser;Password=p@ssw0rd"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="AppSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="" name="AppSqlMembershipProvider" type="Spring.Web.Providers.MembershipProviderAdapter, Spring.Web"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AppSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="" name="AppSqlRoleProvider" type="Spring.Web.Providers.RoleProviderAdapter, Spring.Web"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <profile defaultProvider="AppSqlProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AppSqlProfileProvider" type="Spring.Web.Providers.ProfileProviderAdapter, Spring.Web" connectionStringName=""/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="Greeting" type="String"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

auth-config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

  <object id="AppSqlMembershipProvider" type="Spring.Web.Providers.ConfigurableSqlMembershipProvider">
    <property name="connectionStringName" value="ApplicationServices" />
    <property name="parameters">
      <name-values>
        <add key="description" value="membershipprovider description" />
      </name-values>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object id="AppSqlRoleProvider" type="Spring.Web.Providers.ConfigurableSqlRoleProvider">
    <property name="connectionStringName" value="ApplicationServices" />
    <property name="parameters">
      <name-values>
        <add key="description" value="roleprovider description" />
      </name-values>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object id="AppSqlProfileProvider" type="Spring.Web.Providers.ConfigurableSqlProfileProvider">
    <property name="connectionStringName" value="ApplicationServices" />
    <property name="parameters">
      <name-values>
        <add key="description" value="profileprovider description" />
      </name-values>
    </property>
  </object>

</objects>
```

My `MembershipProvider` is configured in core-config.xml:

```xml
<object id="AccountMembershipService" type="App.Core.Services.AccountMembershipService, App.Core.Services" >
  <constructor-arg name="provider" ref="AppSqlMembershipProvider"/>      <!-- see auth-config.xml for membership provider -->
</object>
```

As I mentioned before, I can inject the `Service` no problem in my web app but I can't seem to get my test to work correctly:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class AccountMembershipServiceTest 
{
    protected IMembershipService AccountMembershipService { get; set; }   // properyt injected
    [Test]
    public void SanityCheck()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(this.AccountMembershipService);            
    }        
}
```

But, alas....failure:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: App.Tests.dll ------

Test 'App.Tests.IntegrationTesting.AccountMembershipServiceTest.SanityCheck' failed: 
  Expected: not null
  But was:  null
    Integration\AccountMembershipServiceTest.cs(23,0): at App.Tests.IntegrationTesting.AccountMembershipServiceTest.SanityCheck()

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 1.80 seconds (NUnit 2.5.5).
```

Anyone else having the same problem or has tackled this as well with Spring.NET?

NOTE:  All of my other configured objects in my unit/integration testing application works, only my membership provider is being problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your test code and not in the membership configuration or Spring.NET context configuration.

To use [Spring.NET dependency injected tests](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/testing.html#testing-fixture-di), your test

- should inherit from one of the Spring.NET test base classes
- should have public properties to inject into (using the default auto-wire by type) - if your property is protected, it'll be null and you get the failed testresult from your question
- should specify the config locations

For instance:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class AccountMembershipServiceTest : 
             AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests
{
  // public properties will be auto-wired by type:
  public IMembershipService AccountMembershipService { get; set; }

  protected override string[] ConfigLocations { ... }
}
```

If you want to [use protected fields for your dependencies](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/testing.html#testing-fixture-di-field), then you should use protected fields, not properties and set `PopulateProtectedVariables = true` in your test constructor:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class AccountMembershipServiceTest :
             AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests
{
    public AccountMembershipServiceTest ()
    {
        PopulateProtectedVariables = true;
    }

    // protected fields will be looked up in the container by field name:
    protected IMembershipService AccountMembershipService;


    protected override string[] ConfigLocations { ... }
}
```

I suspect your membership configuration is actually correct:

- you have added `app.config` to your unit test project [with a `<system.web><membership ...>...</system.web>` section](http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2007/12/30/118071.aspx)
- you used the [fully qualified type name (include the assembly)](http://forums.asp.net/t/1270044.aspx/1) in the membership `type=""` configuration

Comment: reference: https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/blob/master/spring-questions/q8981997_membership_provider_in_unit_test/Program.cs

Comment: I may have been hiding too much details in my test.  My 'AccountMembershipServiceTest' is actually inheriting from another class that inherits from 'AbstractTransactionalDbProviderSpringContextTests'.  I tried 'AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests 
' and 'AbstractSpringContextTests'....still no dice.  I can see the objects configured, but it's not injecting.  I'm going to do a deep dive on this over the weekend.

Comment: Not sure why I was forcing protected there.  Made them public and set auto-wire to auto detect.

Comment: Great it worked out for you. I'm not sure why you'd have to manually set auto-wire to autodetect though. Btw - in comments you can use a backtick (``) instead of a single quote (') to apply code formatting: 'AbstractSpringContextTests' becomes `AbstractSpringContextTests`. This works in questions and answers too.

Comment: Ah, thanks! As for autodetect, that wasn't part of the fix.  I was playing around with some of the attributes but I just left it to autodetect.