# Disable dependency checking for TestContext

Tags: c#, spring, mstest, spring.net

I have created MSTest using `Spring`. In this test I use [TestContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx).

```
[TestClass]
public class Test : AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
    }

    protected override string[] ConfigLocations
    {
        get
        {
            return new string[] { "~/Configuration/spring.config"};
        }
    }

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through object property
>   'TestContext': Set this property value or disable dependency checking
>   for this object..

How can I disable the dependency injection for the `TestContext` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Spring.net uses autowire by type to populate properties on `TestClass`es; iirc you can override this by forcing [field level injection](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/testing.html#testing-fixture-di-field). You might find this [earlier answer of mine useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003195/322283) when configuring field level injection on tests. I think this is the way to go in your case.

Disabling dependency checking for the `TestContext` property would require configuring your `Test` class, which would basically defeat the purpose of using `AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests` in the first place. I think this is a normal autowire message that's somewhat misleading in the context of integration testing.

You can opt not to use dependency injection at all by not inheriting from `AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests`, but from it base class`AbstractSpringContextTests`; but that has the downside of not doing any injection at all.